# How to extract the results from the R console?

Tags: r, strsplit

I have an output in R console as

```
[1] " abc "
```

I want to print the value `abc` in another R code without `[1]` and  `" "` (double quotes). I have tried `strsplit` but not able to omit `[1]` and `" "`.

Comment: You can use `trimws(yourstring)` and then wrap with `cat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need this for printing,

```
cat(str1, '\n')
#abc
```

It could be also

```
as.symbol(trimws(str1))
#abc
```